# Move elements toward each other

Tags: image, animation

I want to create a click event that will have two photos on opposite corners of the screen move towards each other, once they collide, they move back in the direction they came from.

I am having trouble placing an image on the top right corner. I tried using "float: right" but when I tried that, my function does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place the images on the top right corner you should use absolute positioning:

```
.class {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
```

Also do you really need javascript to animate this?
It would be better and more performatic to do it with some CSS. Checkout this fiddle I made: https://jsfiddle.net/jv5et9L0/

In the fiddle I use absolute positioning to put the elements where I want, and then, through Javascript, I add apply the `transform()` property on my CSS. The animation occurs because I have set the `transition` property on the `.item` class.

Comment: thank you for this. It is a lot simpler than what I was trying to do.